# How can I find a number $a$ such that this limit is 1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I want to find the number $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{ax+b}-2}{x}=1$.

First of all, I know that $b$ has to be 4, because the limit of the numerator has to be zero because the denominator is zero when we take its limit.

My problem is with the number 
$a$. I need help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Amzoti $a$ and $b$ need to be numbers, i.e. constants, i.e. *independent* of $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplying by the conjugate gives:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}-2}{x}=\frac{ax+b-4}{x(\sqrt{ax+b}+2)}.
$$

As you already observed, you need $b=4$, for otherwise the limit is infinite.
Then you can simplify by $x$.

Now the limit is:
$$
\frac{a}{\sqrt{4}+2}=\frac{a}{4}.
$$

So you want $a=4$.

Answer (score 0):

As $x\rightarrow 0$, the square root behaves as $$\sqrt{ax+b}=\sqrt{b}\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{b}x} \sim \sqrt{b}\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{a}{b}x+O(x^2)\right).$$
Subtracting the $2$ and dividing by $x$, we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}-2}{x}\sim\frac{\sqrt{b}-2}{x}+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}+O(x).
$$
For the first (diverging) term to vanish, you need $b=4$; to make the second (constant) term equal to $1$, you also need $a=4$.

Answer (score 0):

When $a=b=4$. We can calculate the binomial series of $\sqrt{ax+b}$ and we find that

$$\sqrt{ax+b} \sim \sqrt{b} + \frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}x + \cdots$$

Using this approximation, we see that

$$\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}-2}{x} \sim \frac{\sqrt{b}-2}{x} + \frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}} + \cdots $$

where the tail "$+\cdots$" consists of terms divisible by $x$. Assuming that $\sqrt{b} \neq 2$, the limit is undefined as $x \to 0$. If $\sqrt{b} = 2$, i.e. $b=4$ then we have:

$$\frac{\sqrt{ax+4}-2}{x} \sim \frac{a}{4}-\frac{a^2}{64}x + \cdots $$

where the tail "$+\cdots$" consists of terms divisible by $x^2$. In this case, the limit as $x \to 0$ is $\frac{1}{4}a$ and so we need $a=4$. It follows that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4x+4}-2}{x}\right) = 1 \, . $$

Comment: Except when $b=4$.

Answer (score 0):

As you have figured out the value of $ b $ to be $4 $ hence now the limit will take the form of $ 0/0$ . Hence by applying L'Hopitals rule we get
$$ \lim_{x\to 0 } \frac {a}{2\sqrt{ax+4}} = 1$$
Now we can apply limits by direct substitution and after doing that we get 
$$ \frac {a}{4} = 1 $$ 
Solving this we will get $$ a = 4 $$

Answer (score -2):

multiply by the conjugate on both sides of the equal sign and you get

$$\frac{ax+b-4}x = \sqrt{ax+b}+2$$
multiply by x and plug 4 into b

$$ax+4-4 = x(\sqrt{ax+4}+2)$$
cross out the x's

$$a = \sqrt{ax+4}+2$$
set $x=0$ because $\lim_{x\to 0}$

$$ a = \sqrt{4}+2$$
    $$a=4$$